# Как передать ID запроса через весь http запрос?

Tags: java, http, логирование, spring-boot, logback

Есть SpringBoot проект. В контроллере принимается запрос с уникальным ID, дальше работа кипит в сервисах и более низкоуровневых местах. Как правильно передать этот ID через весь запрос? Задача стоит для упорядочевания системы логирования и мне кажется, что пихать ID запроса во все сигнатуры всех методов просто чтобы указать ID запроса в логах не правильно.

Возможно, это можно сделать с AOP?
М.б. есть какоето готовое решение?
Спасибо за помощью!

Comment: Этот ID нужен только для логирования?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да, абсолютно верно.